# ASP.NET project shows : System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'Food_Id' error

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, .net, web

```
return _entities.Restaurant.Where(x => x.Deleted != true).ToList();
```

This line shows the following error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'Food_Id'

I don't have any column named `Food_Id` in any table or in model.
I don't find any word with name `Food_Id` in the whole project.

Project is on .NET Framework 4.5

Please help..

Comment: Dig deeper -- for example, `Restaurant` may ultimately bind to a view in the database that uses a query where `Food_Id` does appear. Use SQL Server Profiler if needed to capture exact queries. The one thing you know for certain is that the computer isn't lying to you, so somewhere, somehow, a query is being executed that inappropriately mentions `Food_Id`.

Comment: Did you look into relactionships?

Comment: this table doesn't have any relation with other tables

Comment: i also tried to remove the code in the view but still is throw the error

Answer (score 1):

May be u have index with this name.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33552137)